# MVVM ListBox Mouse Click not working but MouseDoubleClick is

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to get my program to copy a textblock from a grid to the Clipboard after it has successfully done it once.  I have a SelectionChanged event that copies the data to the clipboard I than go to an editor paste the clipboard and it works fine.  I than copy some other data to the clipboard.  I than switch back to the program and double click the mouse to copy the data to the clip board again.  I would like to just use the `MouseDown` or `MouseLeftButtonClick` event but I can't seem to get them to work.  Do only some Mouse events work in this scenario?

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Width="auto" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Width="130" Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" x:Name="TextSelected" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="5,0,10,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <TextBlock Width="150" Grid.Column="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" x:Name="TextCommand" Text="{Binding Command}" Margin="0,0,10,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <TextBlock Width="200" Grid.Column="2" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" x:Name="TextLocation" Text="{Binding Location}" Margin="0,0,10,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddItemBtn}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AddItemList2,Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>

        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddItemBtn}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AddItemList2,Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture `PreviewMouseDown` or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` instead.

For example:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseDownCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AddItemList2,Path=SelectedItem}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

The reason that `MouseDown` and `MouseLeftButtonDown` does not work as you expected is because those are **bubbling** events that are raised by the `ListBoxItem` which are already handled by the `ListBoxItem` itself.

> In applications, it is quite common to just handle a bubbling routed event on the object that raised it

`PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` are **tunneling** events which are invoked on your root element first then travels through the child elements. Usually, we `bind` the root element (maybe a `UserControl` or `Window`) to the `DataContext` thus giving you the opportunity to handle the event there.

You can read more about Tunneling/Bubbling events here (quoted statement above also taken here): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview